# Steam LAN "In-home steaming" not working on Chrome OS (via crouton)

Tags: steam, lan, chroot, crouton, chromeos

I installed Ubuntu xenial on my Chromebook via crouton, and after navigating through "locales" problems not being able to run gnome-terminal, mounting problems on my sdcard, and video API problems, I managed to get it to work very well on my Asus C202.

However all network manipulating programs are blocked, including the network manager found in gnome settings. When I run Steam, the other computers on the LAN don't recognize it at all, and the Chromebook does not see other devices on the network when in chroot (ssh and media sharing doesn't work, as if I am offline), however internet access exists and runs without latency problems.

How can I configure Chrome OS to make itself visible on the network, and/or allow chroot to manipulate it? Or if the network is channeled through Chrome OS, how can I configure Ubuntu to make itself recognizable on the LAN? My intention is th stream games on Steam through the LAN, the Chromebook being a client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If people are still having problems, the following commands worked well for me:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 27031 -j ACCEPT  
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 27036 -j ACCEPT  
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 27036 -j ACCEPT  
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 27037 -j ACCEPT
```

as well as the later suggested

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 37804 -j ACCEPT
```

I input all of them into the Chrome shell (I mean crosh, NOT inside the chroot or the host computer), and got both Steam to recognize other computers on the LAN, and game streaming to work. Tested video, and mouse keyboard input, all of which work without any problems. Did not test sound however, but I'm sure it works as well.

To find this I had to navigate through one post referring to the other, and in the end I found it on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Crouton/comments/1xj9qz/has_anyone_been_able_to_use_steam_inhome_streaming/chi5m30/).